# Python Tkinter mainloop increases processing time in multithread application

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, optimization, tkinter

In my application, I have a process which runs on another thread, takes a few seconds to complete and only needs to be done once. I also have a loading window which would let users know that the application is still running and let them cancel the process. This loading window calls a function every 0.5s to update the message : Processing., Processing.. or Processing... in a cycle.

The problem I have is that the computing time increases significantly with the loading window. Here are the 2 different implementation :

Without loading window :

```
processing_thread.start()
processing_thread.join()
```

With loading window :

```
processing_thread.start()

loading_window = LoadingWindow()

while processing_thread.is_alive():
    try:
        loading_window.window.update_idletasks()
        loading_window.window.update()
    except TclError:
        return
```

Note that I don't use `mainloop` but an equivalent implementation which enables me the check if my process is still running - a bit like `join` and `mainloop` merged together ([Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)). I also tested it with mainloop() and it still didn't reduce the processing time in a significant way.

For now, the quick fix was to slow down the loop and add more idle time in the main thread :

```
processing_thread.start()

loading_window = LoadingWindow()

while processing_thread.is_alive():
    try:
        loading_window.window.update_idletasks()
        loading_window.window.update()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    except TclError:
        return
```

This reduced the time to something similar to what I have without the loading window but it brings me 2 problems (as far as I could see) :

- Response time is slower (0.5s at worst)
- The application will end some time after the process ended (0.5s at worst)

Is there a way to implement this without these drawbacks?
Would multiprocessing (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) solve this?

Thank you

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to call `update_idletasks` if you call `update` immediately after. `update` does everything `update_idletasks` does and more.

Comment: Please show the solution you had which used `mainloop`. Using `mainloop` is almost certainly the most efficient way, assuming you're using it properly.

Comment: @BryanOakley the implementation using `mainloop` is something I did only to test. Instead of looping over `update_idletasks` and `update` I called `mainloop`. The problem was that I didn't find a viable way to end the loop when the process ends (I had to do it manually) and only did it to see if it made a difference. As for calling `update_idletasks`, I don't see any significant difference whether I remove it or not. Thanks.